# Is Hebrews 10:28 talking about the past or present

Tags: greek, hebrews, law

I read a few translations of Hebrews 10:28, some translate as present perfect, and some translate as past.

> A man who has gone against the law of Moses **is** put to death without pity on the word of two or three witnesses: (Hebrews 10:28, BBE)

> He that despised Moses’ law **died** without mercy under two or three witnesses: (Hebrews 10:28, KJV)

How should the original Greek be translated?

Comment: Whichever translation is strictly correct, the first describes what the law says, and the second describes what normally happened as a result. So the effective meaning is the same.

Comment: The first alludes that the law still applies after Jesus was crucified.

Comment: Same as "shall be", "is being", and "has been" at once. So, this would fall under (in English) as perfect conditional present. So to answer, in my opinion, both at once. But not quite literally. But if we are to follow current orthodoxy, I don't think it implies that G*d expects us to make this happen in present time. I prefer to think of "should" as what is happening now. Is this happening now? Only in extreme Muslim fundamentalist societies maybe but not in the West.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the literal BLB rendering of Heb 10:28 -

> Anyone having set aside the Law of Moses dies without mercies on the
> basis of two or three witnesses.

There are two verbs in this verse as follows:

- ἀθετήσας = "having set aside" - aorist participle = past completed act of the one who has set aside the law of Moses
- ἀποθνήσκει = "dies" = present indicative active

A better picture of the intended verb tense can be gained from the verses either side.  Let me quote Heb 10:26-29 -

> If we deliberately go on sinning after we have received the knowledge
> of the truth, no further sacrifice for sins remains, but only a
> fearful expectation of judgment and of raging fire that will consume
> all adversaries. Anyone who rejected the law of Moses died without
> mercy on the testimony of two or three witnesses. How much more
> severely do you think one deserves to be punished who has trampled on
> the Son of God, profaned the blood of the covenant that sanctified
> him, and insulted the Spirit of grace?

This paragraph is presenting a classical Hebrew argument:

1. Those who go on sinning after having received the knowledge of the truth have no sacrifice for sins; that is they cannot expect mercy but only "*a fearful expectation of judgment and of raging fire that will consume all adversaries*".
2. As an example from the OT Torah Law, "*Anyone who rejected the law of Moses died without mercy on the testimony of two or three witnesses*."
3. But it will be much worse for Christians because the text says: "*How much more severely do you think one deserves to be punished who has trampled on the Son of God, profaned the blood of the covenant that sanctified him, and insulted the Spirit of grace?*"

Thus, the author of Hebrews summons an example from the Torah to bolster his argument about the need to live described in V26.

Comment: What if the sinning in verse 26 goes about rejecting the law of Moses in verse 28?

Comment: @Kapandaria - "Sin is lawlessness" according to 1 John 3:4 - thus sin is rejecting the law.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/10-28.htm), the original Greek has it in present tense.

> Parallel Commentaries ...
> Greek
> died
> ἀποθνήσκει (apothnēskei)
> Verb - Present Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
> Strong's 599: To be dying, be about to die, wither, decay. From apo and thnesko; to die off.